# Youtube Object #<S> has no method 'playVideo'

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a youtube-playback initiated with javascript.

I initiate a youtubeplayer like this:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '720',
        width: '1280',
        html5: 0,
        videoId: 'i8IXMGHpGBk',
        playerVars: {'modestbranding': 1, 'controls': 1,'showinfo': 0 },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': function(e) {
                if (e.data === 0) {
                    //skrolla här
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Afterwards, I have a function to start the player, like this:

function playvideo(){
    player.playVideo();
}

the player object should have this method according to the docs.

For some reason, I get the error

```
TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'playVideo'
    at Object.Video.$scope.play (file://localhost/Users/kristoffer.nolgren/web/blossa2013dev/js/main.js:7:10)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:74:98
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:156:140
    at Object.e.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:272)
    at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:379)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:156:122)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:24:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:6:470)
    at HTMLDivElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:24:20)
```

I assume angular is interfering with the youtube api, but I don't understan how.

here is the first level of the player-object:

```
Y {b: nb, a: iframe#player, i: div#player, id: 1, d: 2…}
a: iframe#player
b: nb
closure_uid_954797855: 1
d: 3
g: O
h: Object
i: div#player
id: 1
k: Object
o: "player"
s: Array[1]
t: false
```

Comment: this might be because it's being referenced from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that has this prob: check the ID you're providing to

```
new YT.Player()
```

Actually exists in the document.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the YouTube API is being accessed from the file system `file://` rather than `http://`.