# What is a Object #<S> in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to play a youtube-video via the javascript api.

There is a youtube-video-object called

```
myytplayer.playVideo();
```

it's initiated like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '720',
        width: '1280',
        html5: 0,
        videoId: 'i8IXMGHpGBk',
        playerVars: {'modestbranding': 1, 'controls': 1,'showinfo': 0, 'rel': 0 },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': function(e) {
                if (e.data === 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".quizwrapper").offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    document.getElementById('first').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Sometimes, but not always, I get the error :

> TypeError: Object #<`S`> has no method 'playVideo'.

```
if(myytplayer){
  myytplayer.playVideo();
}
```

What does `Object #<S>` even mean?

Comment: why did you create same question:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242186/youtube-object-s-has-no-method-playvideo-when-using-anuglar-js .. you could have edited previous one..?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the line with `if(myytplayer)` and see what the object is set to then I imagine it isn't your object and needs to be initialized this could be a issue with async loading of scripts or multiple other things.  Let me know

Comment: @Sudhir, I actually didn't think I had asked about it.

Comment: @abc123, you were exactly right. I needed to listen for onPlayerReady()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Depending on which browser you are using the console will say `Object#<S>` this really just means your object type, since JavaScript isn't class based it will never say `myytplayer`.

---

### Solution

Setting a breakpoint in any browser on `if(myytplayer){` will show that your `myytplayer` object is either `undefined` or not initialized to your class type.  This could be caused by a multitude of issues.  Likely an initializer needs to be called to set your object up, if this is already being done then you need to look into script loading and make sure your myytplayer script is loaded before the code is executed.